# Set cookie that expire after 1 hour instead of day

Tags: javascript, cookies

I already have that code that set cookie with 1 day validity but i want to set cookie that expire after 1 hour instead of 1 day. How can i achieve this?

HTML

```
<a href="#" onClick="setCookie('see', '000', 1);">Link</a>
```

Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays)
        {
        var exdate=new Date();
        exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
        var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
        document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value + ";path=/";
        }

        function getCookie(c_name)
        {
        var c_value = document.cookie;
        var c_start = c_value.indexOf(" " + c_name + "=");
        if (c_start == -1)
          {
          c_start = c_value.indexOf(c_name + "=");
          }
        if (c_start == -1)
          {
          c_value = null;
          }
        else
          {
          c_start = c_value.indexOf("=", c_start) + 1;
          var c_end = c_value.indexOf(";", c_start);
          if (c_end == -1)
          {
        c_end = c_value.length;
        }
        c_value = unescape(c_value.substring(c_start,c_end));
        }
        return c_value;
        }


        if(getCookie('see')=="000" && document.getElementById('stickyAds'))
        document.getElementById('stickyAds').style.display='none';
 </script>
```

Comment: Might I suggest https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Answer (score 0):

Well 1 day is 24 hours, so 1 hour is 1/24 day

```
<a href="#" onClick="setCookie('see', '000', 1/24);">Link</a>
```

Is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

```
function setCookie(c_name, value, exhours) {
    var exdate = new Date();
    var val = exdate.valueOf();
    val += 3600000 * exhours; // Add exhours * 3600000 milliseconds to the date
    exdate = new Date(val); 
    var c_value = escape(value) + ((exhours == null) ? "" : "; expires=" + exdate.toUTCString());
    document.cookie = c_name + "=" + c_value + ";path=/";
}
```